# VBscript or Powershell script to delete files older than x number of days, following shortcuts/links

Tags: powershell, vbscript

I'm trying to create a script to delete all files in a folder and it's subfolders that are older than 45 days - I know how to do this, the problem is the parent folder in question has several links to other folders within itself - how do I prevent the script from deleting the links (as a link is a file), but instead treats the links like folders and to look "inside" the links for files older than 45 days.

If that's not possible, then is it possible to create a dynamic variable or array so that the script looks inside each folder I need it to and delete any files older than 45 days?  If so, how do I do that.

Currently my only other option would be to create a separate script for each folder (or create code for each script in one file) and either call them individually or use yet another script to call each script.

For reference, this is in a Windows Server 2008 R2 environment

Comment: Really? Why the downvote? Seems like a valid question to me. It's even doable, but you would need to resort to using the WScript.Shell COM object to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't work out a full solution right now. If I get time I'll come back and edit with one. Essentially I would create a function that would call itself recursively for folders anf for links where the .TargetPath was a folder. The creation of the recursive function is pretty standard fair. The only slightly opaque part is getting the .TargetPath of a .lnk file:

```
$sh = New-Object -COM WScript.Shell
$sc = $sh.CreateShortcut('E:\SandBox\ScriptRepository.lnk')
$targetPath = $sc.TargetPath
```

That is the PS way. The VBScript version is pretty much the same with a different variable naming convention and a different method for COM object instantiation.

So here is a more complete solution. I have not set up test folders and files to test it completely, but it should be pretty much what you need:

```
function Remove-OldFile{
    param(
            $Folder
         )
    $sh = New-Object -COM WScript.Shell
    foreach($item in Get-ChildItem $Folder){
        if ($item.PSIsContainer){
            Remove-OldFile $item.FullName
        }elseif($item.Extension -eq '.lnk'){
            Remove-OldFile $sh.CreateShortcut($item.FullName).TargetPath
        }else{
            if(((Get-Date) - $item.CreationTime).Days -gt 45){
                $item.Delete()
            }
        }
    }
}

Remove-OldFile C:\Scripts
```

Just for completeness, here is an untested off the cuff VBS solution. I warn you that it may have some syntax errors, but the logic should be fine.

```
RemoveOldFiles "C:\Scripts"

Sub RemoveOldFiles(strFolderPath)
    Dim oWSH : Set oWSh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Dim oFSO : Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    For Each oFolder in oFSO.GetFolder(strFolderPath).SubFolders
        RemoveOldFiles oFolder.Path
    Next
    For Each oFile in oFSO.GetFolder(strFolderPath).Files
        if LCase(oFSO.GetExtensionName(oFile.Name)) = "lnk" Then
            RemoveOldFiles oWSH.CreateShortcut(oFile.Path).TargetPath
        Else
            If DateDiff("d", oFile.DateCreated, Date) > 45 Then
                oFSO.DeleteFile(oFile)
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks - next question is.  How do I implement that in my current code?

`$a = Get-ChildItem C:\Scripts
foreach($x in $a)
    {
        $y = ((Get-Date) - $x.CreationTime).Days
        if ($y -gt 45 -and $x.PsISContainer -ne $True)
            {$x.Delete()}
    }`

Comment: Well that was the recursive function part that I didn't write yet. Do you grok recursive functions?

Comment: Testing it now, however I did notice one error at `if(((Get-Date) - $x.CreationTime).Days -gt 45){`.
`x.CreationTime` should be `$item.CreationTime`

Comment: Testing is finished and it works.  Thanks!  I didn't think of doing it that way (that and I'm not that familiar with PS yet, been doing most scripts in VBS, but I find VBS confusing and cumbersome)

Comment: One thing to note is that it will not remove shortcuts (which are technically files) that are over 45 days old. I imagine that you can handle tweaks for that if you need to though.

Answer (score 0):

Very high level answer:

```
Loop through all files in current folder.
If `file.name` ends with `.lnk` (we have a link/shortcut).
Get the path of the shortcut with `.TargetPath`
```

You can now pass `.TargetPath` the same way you would pass the name of a subdirectory when you find one to continue recursing through the directory tree.

Comment: My shortcuts do not have a .TargetPath property.

Comment: And to be clear I mean the object that you are working with in PS does not have that property. If you browse to it in explorer then look at the properties in the GUI then it certainly does.

Comment: As I said in the comment to the question though, you can use WScript.Shell to get to the .TargetPath property. You just can't do it natively in the PS FileSystem Provider.

Comment: You didn't say PS was a requirement. I could do this in pure VBScript in a few lines of code, so not sure why you think you would need multiple scripts.

Comment: Well first of all I did not say PS was a requirement. Neither did you say that your answer was VBScript specific.

Comment: Not sure why you think that I am espousing multiple scripts?

Comment: Uhm, howzabout because the TITLE of your question says "VBScript OR Powershell"? And when you looked at my code you couldn't tell it was VBScript and not Powershell? You might be in over your head then.

Comment: I think you need to look at my name and at the name of the person that asked the actual question. I'll give you a hint. They are not the same. I did not ever say that PS was a requirement. Neither did the OP. I did not say that multiple scripts were required. Neither did the OP. I did provide a PS answer so when you provided an answer that did not specified any language at all I commented on it from a PS perspective.

Comment: Touche! However I still think you should have been able to differentiate between VBS and PS just by looking at the code.